# Crystal Report that has group summary only

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that uses two groups for counting sales by year & month.  I would like to know how to display the summaries across the page rather than down.

2009
jan 15
feb 5
etc,

2010
jan 30
feb 18

I would like the report to be as follows:

```
  2009     2010
```

Jan     15       30
Feb      5       18

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cross Tab like this:

1. right click to your report white space > Insert > Cross-Tab...

[image]

Select columns, Rows, Fields to Summarized whatever fields you want.

2. [image]

Then move it to Section 4. Good Luck!